# Emojis corrupted on iOS when using negation with unicode character class escapes

Tags: javascript, ios, regex, unicode, emoji

I'm using regular expressions to remove non-latin and non-emoji characters from strings.

As [Unicode character class escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Unicode_character_class_escape) are now widely supported, I used them to simplify my expressions.

```js
const regex = new RegExp('[^(\\d\\s\\p{Script=Latin}\\p{gc=Punctuation}\\p{Extended_Pictographic})]+', 'gui');

function removeUnsupportedChars(txt: string) {
   return txt.replace(this.characterEx, '');
}
```

This works on PC and on Android. However, on iOS, when using this regular expression, emojis get corrupted and shown as squares.

[image]

I created a minimal [CodePen](https://codepen.io/lizozom-the-sans/pen/GRYxOzp) where the scenario is reproduced with a simplified regex and it seems like on iOS *any usage of negation on the `Extended_Pictographic` class (or any of the other emoji classes) leads to their corruption.*

[image]

Is this a known issue on iOS? Any known workarounds (other than using explicit emoji lists)?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/729609

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, but I'm still curious as for why negation of unicode character classes doesn't work on iOS.

I chose to use a `positive regex` and use `match` to combine the pieces that DO match the regex, instead of using a `negative regex` with `replace`:

```
const regex = /[\d\s\p{Script=Latin}\p{gc=Punctuation}\p{Currency_Symbol}\p{Emoji_Presentation}\p{Extended_Pictographic}]*/gui;

function removeUnsupportedChars(txt: string) {
    const matches = txt.match(this.characterEx) || [];
    return matches.join('');
}
```